# Should AudioBufferSourceNode.stop() need a 'this' binding?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

The following code creates a tone that stops after 500 milliseconds. It's pretty straightforward:

```
// Create audio context and nodes
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 'sine';
oscillator.frequency.value = 250;

// Attach nodes and start tone
oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
oscillator.start();

// Stop the tone after half a second
window.setTimeout(function() {
    oscillator.stop();
}, 500);
```

But when I refactor the call to oscillator.stop() to simply pass the function pointer to `window.setTimeout`, it no longer works - at least in Chrome:

```
window.setTimeout(oscillator.stop, 500); // throws 'Illegal Invocation' exception
```

This initially puzzled me - the only real difference between the calls is that there's no `this` binding to `oscillator` in the second. Explicitly binding `this` does indeed fix the problem:

```
window.setTimeout(oscillator.stop.bind(oscillator), 500); // works perfectly
```

Is this supposed to be how `AudioBufferSourceNode.stop()` needs to be called (with a 'this' context), or is this simply a shortcoming in Chrome's implementation (that presumably falls back on JS rather than directly calling native code)? Should I assume all BOM methods need a `this` binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general, binding would be necessary. With this:

```
setTimeout(oscillator.stop, 500);
```

only `stop()` is referenced as an isolated method/function, not the "context" it is part of, so when it is invoked `stop()` expects `oscillator` as context (`this`) but gets `window` which of course will fail.

Methods calling native code is also required to do proper binding as they are exposed through JavaScript. A different example would be:

```
var getId = document.getElementById;
getId("someId");    // will fail
```

whereas

```
var getId = document.getElementById.bind(document);
getId("someId");    // will work
```

So a bind is necessary here.

Comment: I understand what is happening with the this binding - but I don't know if this is an implementation detail in Chrome or if it's how I should expect the API to work? Especially given that `.stop()` could be native code rather than JavaScript (and therefore not be subject to the same binding behaviour as JS)

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye it's part of JavaScript. Only stop() is referenced.

Comment: I think you misunderstand; I understand perfectly well how `this` binding works and how it gets lost with function pointers in JavaScript. What I don't know is if this should be happening with a BOM method that could be calling native code under the hood, or simply an implementation detail in Google Chrome.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye I could be misunderstanding, but there is no special treatment of native methods - they are exposed through JS and same context requirement applies. You could do this with lets say, var getId = document.getElementById; and it would only work with a bind(document) to it.

Comment: I guess that's what I wanted to confirm - that I should assume that BOM methods need the same kinds of binding. Now I think of the document.getElementById case, it seems fairly obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this at all?  You should use

```
oscillator.stop( audio context.current time + 0.5 );
```

Immediately after the call to start(), instead.

Comment: In Chrome, oscillator.stop did not like me giving it non-integer timeouts. They would fail to fire, but without throwing exceptions. I assume this is a Chromium bug.

Comment: If the suggestion from cwilso doesn't work for you, file a bug at crbug.com/new with an example that illustrates it. I don't really understand what you mean by non-integer timeouts and failing to fire.  stop(time) accepts any positive finite real value for time.  When the oscillator stops, it should fire the onended event. If it doesn't, that's a bug.

Comment: The only comment I'll add is you know stop()'s parameter is in seconds, not milliseconds like setTimeout, right?  If you point me to a bit of code, I'll debug.